# Regex two or more whitespace from end

Tags: javascript, regex

I'd like to know , how make javascript regex to find 3 words from end of string
Original words is "Sunday morning is very beatifull day" after regex ,
the words become "very beatifull day". 
Thanks for your helps.

Comment: Welcome to [so]! At this site you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour] and read **[this](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347937/)**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The regular expression is:

```
(?:\b\S+\b *){3}$
```

See https://regex101.com/r/0Ooeno/3

Answer (score 1):

why use regex pattern ?.simply do with `split(" ").slice(-3)`

```js
var a ="Sunday morning is very beatifull day";
console.log(a.split(" ").slice(-3).join(" "))
```